# How would my Java program process a JS file to extract function names?

Tags: java, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get method name from JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921427/how-to-get-method-name-from-javascript-file)

I want to fetch Java Script function name in my Java file.I mean i want some solution so that i can go traverse my JS File,find out function name & list out them in my Java file.Is there any way so that i link my JS File,its function name with Java?

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the javascript file.  You can try to use the parser from [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/jsc.html), a quick google search shows [this](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.js-engine.rhino/browse_thread/thread/1eff23a8ee57b991) thread discussing how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for help.I have followed Rhino example which are given in "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29#Example",With it i am able to call JS function but if i want to call method of external JS file,it shows me "no such method:hello".How can i solve it?

Comment: I am able to solve above problem.Is there any way that i can know that how many function are there in JS file and what is their name?